# Hudson / Sonar report about compiler warnings

Tags: hudson, jenkins, sonarqube

Is there a plugin to show compiler warnings in Hudson and / or Sonar?

Comment: May be 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/sanity4j/'

Answer (score 2):

Hudson/Jenkins has the [Warnings plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin). There's no similar plugin for Sonar, but I'm wondering if the compiler checks are redundant with the many checks embedded in Sonar (Checkstyle, Sonar Squid, PMD, Findbugs, ...).

Comment: This looks promising - I will try that. Yes Checkstyle, Findbugs, etc gives a lot of feedback, but I am interested in usage of deprecated classes/methods and I know that this info is spit out as compiler warning.

Comment: You can simply activate the rule "Avoid use of deprecated method" in Sonar. No need for plugins !